# Block file access requests

Tags: browser, filesystems, driver, minifilter

How to block file access requests from Chrome/Firefox on the basis of url?

For e.g. `song.mp3` should not be allowed to access if `*.google.com` is being visited.

Comment: Is 'song.mp3' is on local disk drive or on cloud,  such as google .com?

Comment: 'song.mp3' is on local disk drive.